Bash Script to Delete Backup Files Older than 7 Days From a Google Drive Folder
I created an automatic backup of my files from database to google drive and I used cron job to schedule it to execute every day. Now I want to auto delete these files that are older than a week from the google drive directory. Deleting the files stored in my server directory is supposed to delete files older than a week too but the script I wrote deletes every file in the server directory. I used this script:
#!/bin/bash

SERVER_BACKUP_DIR="/path/"
GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID="/path"

ONE_WEEK_THRESHOLD=$(($(date +%s) - 604800))

find "$SERVER_BACKUP_DIR" -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;

FILES=$(gdrive files list --query "'$GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID' in parents" | tail -n +2)

while IFS= read -r line; do
    file_id=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
    file_modified_time=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $3 " " $4}')

    # Convert date and time to Unix timestamp
    modified_time_seconds=$(date -d "$file_modified_time" +%s)

    if [ "$modified_time_seconds" -lt "$ONE_WEEK_THRESHOLD" ]; then
        gdrive files delete "$file_id"
    fi
done <<< "$FILES"

How can I achieve this especially that of the google drive ?
I expected this script to do the job but it gave error saying invalid time format. Seems it can not extract the exact time of the backup files from the google drive in the standard time format.
#!/bin/bash

SERVER_BACKUP_DIR="/path"
GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID="/path"

ONE_WEEK_THRESHOLD=$(($(date +%s) - 604800))

find "$SERVER_BACKUP_DIR" -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;

FILES=$(gdrive files list --query "'$GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID' in parents" | tail -n +2)

while IFS= read -r line; do
    file_id=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
    file_modified_time=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $3 " " $4}')

    # Convert date and time to Unix timestamp
    modified_time_seconds=$(date -d "$file_modified_time" +%s)

    if [ "$modified_time_seconds" -lt "$ONE_WEEK_THRESHOLD" ]; then
        gdrive files delete "$file_id"
    fi
done <<< "$FILES"


See -delete switch of find command!

I often use cd $path || exit ; find . -type f -mtime +7 -print -delete...

You are selecting old files using -mtime. Why do you then test again the modification time inside the while loop?

You use -mtime instead of -ctime. That means, after uploading an old file it is removed immediately. And files with timestamps in the future will stay longer than 1 week.

Why not just read -r file_id x t1 t2 rather than repeated subshell calls to pipe an echo through awk? Also, you're using bash, so why not ((modified_time_seconds < ONE_WEEK_THRESHOLD))?

Also, I think gdrive has a  --no-header option that would save you a pipe to tail.
